# considere the ROI as an image with dimensions reduced in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have applied SLIC superpixel algorithm to get a clustered image. i had generated the mask from that clustered image. now i want to apply this mask on my original image to get the specific region as an image.
this is what i have done.

```
im=imread('IMAGE/image 2.jpg');
[x y]=size(im);
%z=rgb2gray(im);

[l, Am, Sp, d] = slic(im, 10, 15, 1.5, 'mean',10);
SPNUM=size(unique(l),1);
N=length(Am);
th=0;
    %I_final=(zeros(x,y));
for K = 1:SPNUM
    mask=(l==(K));
    MASK= repmat(uint8(mask),[1,1,3]);
    im1=im.*MASK;

end
```

Comment: Where is your question ?

Comment: i am not able to get the specific region as an image. it displays the image with same dimensions...